# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\public\index.html'

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tratando de visualizar el archivo html principal, no he podido dar con la ruta especifica, por mas que he intentado.

#### server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config';

const app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));

app.get('*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile('/public/index.html');
});

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.json({api: "Woks Fine"});
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log("App Start in Port", app.get('port'));
});

export default app;
```

#### Estructura del proyecto

[image: imagen]

Comment: Hecha un vistazo a las rutas en node https://nodejs.org/api/path.html el comando console.log(process.env.PATH);

Answer (score 2):

La ruta debería ser:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile('./public/index.html');
});
```

Recuerda anteponer el punto, porque al no hacerlo estás diciendo que index.html se encuentra en la ruta absoluta **/public/index.html** y no en la ruta relativa **./public/index.html**

Comment: Probé de toda ruta, y nada amigo, pero, igual, cuando retome `Node`, tendré esto en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la posición de creación de Node_modules en el momento en que creas el archivo json y la posición de index.html...[image: Visual Code Proyecto How to make an ecommerce virtual shop]

Comment: ¿Qué debo mirar? ¿Qué acciones debo tomar?

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/300362)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Giate de la imagen (frontend)]

Asi deberia estar la ruta de tus archivos ,preferible saca el archivo server.js a fuera de la ruta  de public,en mi caso la renombre mi carpeta .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Considera mencionar las rutas _por escrito_. Es muy difícil comprender lo que colocaste en las imágenes, además de que [no todos pueden ver tales imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [answer]